Can Mockito @MockBean with some additional settings mock advised Spring component?
I've a simple service & aspect for it:
@Service
public class EzService {

    public void ezMove() {
        System.out.println("EzService#ezMove");
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
class EzServiceAspect {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Around("bean(ezService) && execution(* ezMove())")
    void ezMove(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        System.out.println("@Around: EzServiceAspect#ezMove");
        pjp.proceed();
    }
}

When I trying to test the performance of advised method EzServiceAspect#ezMove, then encounter a problem:

@MockBean of EzService doesn't give the opportunity to Spring create appropriate proxy – as I suppose – and advice doesn't work.


I don't wanna have cheap workaround with @TestCofiguration:
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
class EzServiceAspectConfigMockBeanTest {

    @Autowired EzService ezService;
    @SpyBean EzServiceAspect aspect;
    
    
    @Test
    void test() {
        ezService.ezMove();

        then(aspect).should().ezMove(any());
    }

    
    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        EzService ezService() {
            return Mockito.mock(EzService.class);
        }
    }
}


So, the question is: how can I concisely mock advised EzService in such component-test via @MockBean?

Perhaps, there are some additional Mockito/Spring settings.


GitHub

There aren't, use a test configuration (the solution you don't want). Also your aspect is flawed, never make a void method. ALways return the result of the pjp.proceed(); invocation else it will break proper method invocation and chaining. I would also make the method (and class) public else Mockito might at some point have a problem extending it for spying.

Dear, M. Deinum, It isn't necessary return pjp.proceed() from @Around-advice, when return type of advised method is void. Absolutely no pra ;) Despite the fact, that – as I suppose – your linter highlights It. And I've never faced similar problems from the Mockito. Moreover, make some class public and losing the advantage of package private access for the needs of Mockito...who serves whom?)

Then how about a more "clean code" approach, documenting the fact that the target method has a void return type by using a pointcut like execution(void ezMove()) instead of the generic *, both improving readability and speeding up pointcut matching?

Just always return it, you don't know if your pointcut will call a void method or not. If you do do you really need an aspect as it doesn't seem to be very broad/crosscutting then. YOu aren't the first which is suddenly suprised that code stopped working when they added an around advice and not returning stuff. Hence just always return to avoid problems in the future (it doesn't hurt and solves more then if you don't). Anyways the bean is going to be replaced as just a plain mock if you want it as a bean you need a configuration class. Else it isn't a bean and as such doesn't get processed.

@M. Deinum, guys from Spring in their docsrecomended return pjp.proceed(); even from void method too. So, I've to agree with you and thanks

@kriegaex, thanks for good point and glad to see you again
